# Scrapyd: how to pass multiple setting values to scrapy service

Tags: python, urllib2, scrapy, urllib, web-crawler

Here is an example in scrapy document:

```
$ curl http://localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project=myproject -d spider=somespider -d setting=DOWNLOAD_DELAY=2 -d arg1=val1
```

But if I want to set both DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 2 and CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 4, how to do? 
And how to do it with urllib2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two solutions.

First one, try this:

```
$ curl http://localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project=myproject -d spider=somespider -d setting=DOWNLOAD_DELAY=2 -d setting=CONCURRENT_REQUESTS=4 -d arg1=val1
```

Second one: New a file named `settings.py` in `myproject` folder(the directory with the `pipelines.py` and `items.py`). And put all your settings in it. Here's an [example](https://github.com/scrapy/dirbot/blob/master/dirbot/settings.py).

Comment: What do you want to do with urllib2? To deploy your project? Maybe [this](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/commands/deploy.py) will help. BTW, I strongly recommend you to put all your settings in the `settings.py`.

Comment: I want to deploy my project. I have several spiders. Most of settings are in setting.py. but I want to have some special settings with each spider. Thank you, I solve the problem by myself.

Comment: Hi @ZhangJiuzhou, how did you go about putting multiple settings in your POST request?  I am also struggling to understand how to put multiple settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with passing list to setting argument

```
import requests
r = requests.post('http://localhost:6800/schedule.json', data={
        'project': 'your_project',
        'spider': 'your_spider',
        'url': url,
        'setting': ['key1=value1', 'key2=value2']
        })
```